# Linking static libraries to XCode Project libMWPhotoBrowser.a

Tags: ios, mwphotobrowser

I'm trying to add MWPhotoBrowser as a static library to my project.

I've added MWPhotoBrowser.xcodeproj and the instructions for adding a static library are to know go to build phases and add libMWPhotoBrowser.a - I think this is a product of the MWPhotoBrowser build (from what I've ready and the little that I understand) but I'm not sure what to do here?

I go to build phases and click add but, obviously, libMWPhotoBrowser.a is not showing up and I'm not sure why - can anybody else point me in the right direction on what to do next?

Comment: Did you try to just drag and drop your .a file into the Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries section? Also make sure you have build the .a file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem you are facing here is that you didn't build your static lib: `libMWPhotoBrowser.a` from the `MWPhotoBrowser.xcodeproj` you have added to your project. Once this is built you can add the .a file from the build phase section or just make a drag and drop of the file there.